# jQuery find previous button by ID (which will have different names)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I am trying to get the previous button so that I can change its text to something else once someone selects a value from a select box.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Type</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dd1" role="menu">
             <li><a href="#" data-info="blah1">For Sale</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-info="blah1">Wanted</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Location</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dd2" role="menu">
             <li><a href="#" data-info="somewhere">Somewhere</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-info="elsewhere">Elsewhere</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
</div>

$('.search-panel #dd1, .search-panel #dd2').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).data("info");

    $(this).prev().find('#search_concept').text($(this).text());
});
```

So the click event starts from **THIS** which is the **a href="#" data-info="blah1">[value here]< /a>** tag. So I am trying to go back to the **< button>** tag so that I can change the text **Type** to whatever was selected.

I've tried:

```
$(this).prev().find('#search_concept').text($(this).text());
and
$(this).prev().prev().find('#search_concept').text($(this).text());
and
$(this).prev().prev().children().find('#search_concept').text($(this).text());
and
$(this).prev().children().find('#search_concept').text($(this).text());
```

And I can't seem to find it....

**fixed**

```
$('.search-panel #dd1, .search-panel #dd2').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).data("info");

    $(this).parents('.search-panel').find('button').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet uses jQuery's `.parents` to locate a button.

`$(this).parents(selector)` will find any parent elements that have the specified selector.

Then `.find(selector)` will search that parent element for the specified selector.

Then you can assign that to a variable and use the element.

```js
$('.search-panel #dd1').find('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var param = $(this).data("info");
  var text = $(this).text();

  // Assign element to variable for later manipulation
  var $button = $(this).parents('.search-panel').find('button');

  // eg: Replace button text (replaces all content including html)
  // $button.text(text)

  // eg: Find another element inside $button and replace the text
  // $button.find('#search_concept').text(text)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Type</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dd1" role="menu">
             <li><a href="#" data-info="blah1">For Sale</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-info="blah1">Wanted</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't have multiple SAME ids.

```
$(this).parents().find("button #search_concept").text($(this).text());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the first selector will do what the OP is asking?

Comment: There will be multipule IDs that will be the same and I do not want to change all the select boxes' text.

Comment: Assuming it that space in between `button #search_concept`is typo.

Comment: Space between was no typo btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated ids which can make things messy. I would change concept of relaying on id to some other selectors, e.g classes:

And so such way you can treat `search-panel` group as a widget, and javascript going to be rewritten as:

```js
$('.search-panel').each(function() {
  var search_concept = $(this).find(".search_concept");
  $(this).find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).data("info");
    search_concept.text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="search_concept">Type</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dd" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="#" data-info="blah1">For Sale</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" data-info="blah1">Wanted</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="search_concept">Location</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dd" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="#" data-info="somewhere">Somewhere</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" data-info="elsewhere">Elsewhere</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
    </div>
```

This approach will arguably improve portability.